# Detect the height auto using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, height

I have a `div` with a fixed height (ex: 500px). This div contains some html block elements inside it. What i want to achieve is to detect using javascript what height whould have my div if i will set height auto insted of that fixed height.

```
<div id="someId" style="height: 500px;">
    <p>My paragraf</p>
    <h1>My heading</h1>
</div>
```

In other order of words, i want to get the height of the div without considering the white space from the bottom.

Is there any way i can do this?

Comment: In case you want to ask me why i used 500px from the start, the answere is: this div is a contextual menu, means that it's as tall as the html document, but on mobile devices i want not to display the white space from the bottom.

Comment: What if you create another div (in this div) and get the height of this with: $('.innnerDIV').height() ?

Comment: i think you can also use css http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/df3d5n2b/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found a solution:

```
$('#someId').clone().attr('id', 'cloneId').appendTo('body');
$('#someId').css({'height':'auto','opacity':'0'});
alert($('#someId').height()+'px');
```

First i dupplicate my div, then i set the clone div height auto, and after that i get it's height.

Comment: yes should work, but now you are adding another div to the body? This doesn't mess up your view?

Comment: hmm, if it's not displayed I would guess the `height()` would show wrong results. But I will take your word for it and assume this works :D

Comment: If i make it invisible (opacity:0) means that it won't crash the design and in the same time i can get it's height. Thanks;

Comment: Save the original height setting, change it to auto, get your data, and set height back. This will give you want you want and will not be visible to the naked eye.
It would be less CPU consuming (and less dangerous in large websites or angular based websites) than duplicating the entire thing..

Answer (score 1):

check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sarawagiakash/dw73mzuw)

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var previousHgt=$("div").height();
    var getheightWhenAuto=($("div").css("height","auto").height());
    $("div").css("height",previousHgt   )
    alert(getheightWhenAuto);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you calculate the height of the children and add up? Something like:

```
<div id="#someId" style="height: 500px;">
    <p>My paragraf</p>
    <h1>My heading</h1>
</div>
```

So in jQuery

```
var height = $('#someId > p').height()+$('#someId > h1').height();
```

**Edit:**
Or if you want something general:

```
var height = 0;
$( "#someId" ).children().each(function() {
  height = height + $(this).height();
});
```